# How to hide/show columns from a table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to **hide** columns and the corresponding row data for that column. When I click on a particular table header.

But I only end up with hiding the other table headers. I don't even have to click the particular table header for the others to dissapear.

**This is what I have for the moment.**

```
<th data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">totalFillingstops</th>
<th id="demo" class="collapse">fd1</th>
<th id="demo" class="collapse">channel 2</th>
<th id="demo" class="collapse">channel 3</th>
<th id="demo" class="collapse">fd1NoWinding</th>
```

So when I click the totalFillingStops header I want to collapse/show the following columns fd1, channel 2, ... and so on

This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80d7rjf5/2/). I'm new to front end programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, tables do not work that way. Hiding the `<th>` will not hide the corresponding `<td>` item in the tbody.

Also, using an ID more than once in HTML is not valid.

Here is a jsfiddle with an example of what I believe will do what you need it to:

https://jsfiddle.net/rjutvsdz/1/

Comment: Or here's how to do it without having to write any javascript:

https://jsfiddle.net/jjL8knjq/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
  function collapseColumn(index) {
            //hide column header
            $("table th").eq(index).addClass("hidden");
            $("table tr").each(function() {
                //hide column's  tds
                $(this).find('td').eq(index).addClass("hidden");
            });
        }
    function unCollapseColumn(index) {
            //hide column header
            $("table th").eq(index).removeClass("hidden");
            $("table tr").each(function() {
                //hide column's  tds
                $(this).find('td').eq(index).removeClass("hidden");
            });
        }
$("table th").eq(0).click(function(){
     collapseColumn(2);
});
```

Comment: And how exactly do I use this?